Repairing end of 4” pvc pipe - circle shape collapsed
My downspout at the corner of my garage ends directly on the driveway such that the water runs into the garden bed immediately adjacent and pools there anytime it rains. To make matters more challenging, the front walkway is on the other side of the garden, so the only way to drain the water away was to go under the concrete walkway.
I was able to place a 4” pvc under the concrete (used a pressure washer like a hydro drill and tapped the pipe in as I went). All good, except…there was a large branch under the concrete that collapsed the end of the pipe as it was coming through. Once I realized this, I was able to get to the branch and saw it out, but now the first 6 inches or so of the length of the pipe is folded (imagine the pipe smiling, mocking my efforts).
One solution could be to knock more pipe in from the other side, saw off the bent part, and go. I’m a little concerned about having enough pipe on the other end if I do this, however. I’m wondering if there’s a way to un-collapse the pipe. Maybe something to stick in it and expand it such that the pipe regains its shape? Does such a method exist? Any other suggestions?

It isn't clear why the deformation is a problem. Is it merely unattractive or bothersome in principle, or do you need to make a connection that demands the pipe be properly round? Knowing your end objective will help guide our suggestions. Also, if you can share a photo showing the extent of the damage, that'll be helpful too. Welcome to DIY!

You could try warming it with a heat gun or blow torch to soften it and then moulding it with your (gloved) hands,  when you get that stuff warm enough it goes leathery, so if you have a disk or ring the right size it should be easy to restore the end
Unless it's going to take hours to get some more pipe
assuming heat does not work the easiest solution is probably to join some more pipe on the good end and push further through.
I am not aware of any common tool intended for reshaping crushed pipes but some sort of reinforced water balloon (fed from your pressure washer) or bullet-shape on a rope (drawn through from the good end to the squashed part) can probably do it.

Easiest solution is to simply get a coupler and another length of pipe.  Use the coupler to connect the new pipe to the "tapped" end, tap it through some more, and cut off the damaged portion.  That way you're assured of having sufficient length.
That, or get a cylindrical wedge, i.e. shaped like a bullet—maybe you can form it out of scrap wood—and drive it through the pipe.  Might have to start with a small wedge and work your way up to a larger one.
